# How to set default value in bootstrap-select dropdown with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-select

Here is the dropdown HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="edit-item_condition">
       <option data-tokens="1">Option 1</option>
       <option data-tokens="2">Option 2</option>
       <option data-tokens="3">Option 3</option>
       <option data-tokens="4">Option 4</option>
       <option data-tokens="5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set default value that I fetch from DB

```
 const editItem = new Vue({
            el: "#editItem",
            data: {
                items: null,
                selectedItem: null,
            },
            methods: {
                set_dropdown_default(item) {
                    try {
                        this.selectedItem = item;
                        $('.edit-item_condition').selectpicker('val', parseInt(this.selectedItem.properties.condition));
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                },
```

The `this.selectedItem.properties.condition` in my example is "2". Checked and proved in debugger. Nevertheless, the dropdown is not affected and shows "Option 1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the `select` tag via v-model with the needed option value, here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
  data:{
    selected: 4
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option value="1">Frist</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
    
  </select>
  
  
  <p>Selected item: {{selected}}</p>
</div>
```

so in your example you could do

```
<select class="form-control" id="edit-item_condition" v-model="selectedItem.properties.condition">
```

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)

Comment: In my case, it was a bit more complicated, since I get item object from the previous modal, so I still have to set it dynamically on submit and accordingly in the method. Anyway, your answer is absolutely correct. Thank you.